# Angular.JS, Data-binding in a directive template When the form validation checking

Tags: angularjs

I have a binding problem. I want to validate the email address

A. `<input type="email" required ng-model="emailAddress" name="{{name}}" />`

B. `<input type="email" required ng-model="emailAddress" name="emailAddress2" />`

'A' is Not working, I want to working using 'A' expression.

But, B is Working.

I want to binding expression Using 'A' Expression.

```
.directive('emailInput', function() {
        return {
            require: '^form',
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<input type="email" required ng-model="emailAddress" name="{{name}}" />',
            scope: {
                send2: '&'
            },          
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
                    scope.name="emailAddress2"; // <--- this is not binding to input element

            }
        };
    });
```

HTML

```
<email-input></email-input> inputIsValid={{myForm.emailAddress2.$valid}}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the binding variable name? It might cause conflict since you are using the same built-in attr name. For example, `name="{{alias}}"` then, `scope.alias="emailAddress2"`.

Comment: I was tested your proposal, Same Variable is not problem, 
I assume that not binding problem.  When the template contents is insert into <email-input> element dynamically, Not Binding Problem Occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the name and then compile the input-element for angular to notice the new name and make $valid work.

```
...
link: function (scope, elem) {
   var input = elem.children()[0];
   input.name = "emailAddress2";
   $compile(input)(scope);
}
...
```

Comment: Thank Your Help. I want to change in the template content. <attrs.name> is not binding to element which in the template.

Comment: Ahh, yes you would change the email-input, instead. You could use elem.children()[0].name = "emailAddress2", but you still would probably have use $compile on the element to get the $valid-function to work.

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem. Your Comment is working. Thank you.

Comment: I've got it, I will do it in the future. Im beginner in stackoverflow, Understand me.

Answer (score 0):

From your HTML, modify it as follows:

```
<email-input name="name"></email-input> inputIsValid={{myForm.emailAddress2.$valid}}
```

Now, whatever value you change in the directive (`scope.name = "whatever"`) will bind to the template.
I hope it helps.